Spring Batch Remote Chunking Retry Not Working for Worker Exceptions
Working with Spring Batch integration for remote chunk processing, where I have a manager and a worker. The issue occurs when the worker throws a RuntimeException. I need to retry the particular chunk, but the retry functionality does not seem to be working as expected.
I would like to know if Spring Batch's remote chunking really supports retrying failed chunks when a RuntimeException occurs on the worker. If yes, could someone please provide a working example of how to properly configure the retry functionality for remote chunking?
Here's a brief overview of my current setup:

Manager: Configured with RemoteChunkingManagerStepBuilder.
Worker: Configured with RemoteChunkingWorkerBuilder.
Exception Handling: Using RetryTemplate but unable to trigger the retry on chunk failure.

tried retry functionality but not working. provide a working example

FaultTolerantStepBuilder which is part of the ChunkStepBuilder is looking for failure during the sending the items to output Channel. Not to give a try of failed items at worker nodes. pls correct me if i misinterpreted.
